# Jquery replace text without erasing the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#firstshow .dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){  
        $('#firstshow button b').html(this);
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstshow">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>36</b>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">12</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">24</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">36</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The main idea is to make this code like the classic html select.

The reason I do this is because I didn't figure out how to change the blue hover in option menu.

Run code snippet and click the li content. As you see the next time the content is removing from my list and that is my problem. How can I keep the li data and not removing in my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner-most statement should be:

```
$('#firstshow button b').text($(this).text());
```

The way you had it you used the `a` element object as the HTML code for the buttons text, but you don't want to assign the element, but its text. So:

- Assign `$(this).text()`
- Assign it with `text()` not with `html()` -- better practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's about the part `.html(this)` in your code. The `this` variable is a reference to the dom object that is being clicked. When you set this as the html of the displayed select value, it moves the dom object and replaces whatever was displayed.

To overcome this set the displayed value to the text value of the element that is being clicked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#firstshow .dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){  
        $('#firstshow button b').html($(this).text());
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstshow">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>36</b>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">12</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">24</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">36</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```